# Read data from Excel and search it in df, TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tolist

I read a lot about this Error, but I couldn't find a solution for me.

I have an Excel with 3 columns in which I store keywords. I want to read these keywords and search it in a Pandas Dataframe. The Code below gives me an Error:

```
    # Error 
    if Keywords_EKN[y] in df.iloc[x, 12]:
    TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float
```

The Code:

```
    df_Dienstleister = pd.read_excel('Dienstleister.xlsx', header=None)
    Keywords_Dritte = df_Dienstleister.values.T[0].tolist()
    Keywords_EDT = df_Dienstleister.values.T[1].tolist()
    Keywords_EKN = df_Dienstleister.values.T[2].tolist()

    # Search for Keywords in df and replace some new data
    # There is another Excel in df
       for x in range(0, rows-1):
           for y in range(0, number_of_Keywords_EKN):
               if Keywords_EKN[y] in df.iloc[x, 12]:
                   df.iloc[x, 13] = "EKN"
           for z in range(0, number_of_Keywords_EDT):
               if (Keywords_EDT[z] in df.iloc[x, 12]):  
                   df.iloc[x, 13] = "EDT"
           for w in range(0, number_of_Keywords_Dritte):
               if  (Keywords_Dritte[w] in df.iloc[x, 12]) :
                  df.iloc[x, 13] = "Dritte"
```

But when I read just one column from Excel and write the another Keywords in the Code, it works fine: (I have more Keywords in EKN and EDT, it's just to show my problem)

```
Keywords_Dritte = df_Dienstleister.values.T[0].tolist()
Keywords_EKN = ['EKN']
Keywords_EDT = ['EDT']
```

The ouput of print(Keywords_EKN[y]) is

```
EKN
nan
```

I don't know, what's the problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a guess: `EKN` is empty, so it's probably filled with `NaN` which has tpye `float`?

Comment: Please provide sample data not in a picture. For example you can use: `df[['BWE', 'EDT', 'EKN']].iloc[:6].to_dict()` after loading. and post the code here. You code seems overcomplicated btw.

Comment: @Timus "EKN" ist not empty. I added some more random data into it, and I have the same Error.

Comment: Have you provided string data for all cells, one single `NaN` is enough for the error? I'd recommend a `df = df.fillna("")` directly after reading the data from the csv (assumption: all provided data are strings).

Comment: Your're right @Timus. There are two NaN cells. All provided data are not strings but I use just one column of df and it is just string. with your code `df = df.fillna("")` I got no error more, but no output. 
The Lukas's answer solved the problem but I got another error `argument of type 'float' is not iterable` .  And I have no clue why.
Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EKN` contains np.nan which is `float` value (or any other non-string value). You can invoke the error with code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

kw = ['EKN', np.nan] # or 2, 2.3,...any non-string value
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': ["EKN", "KNE", "xs"]})

for y in range(0, len(kw)):
    if kw[y] in df.iloc[0, 0]:
        print('found')
```

Result is error because `in` expects `string` from `kw[y]` but got `float`. Solution could be quite simple:

```
if str(kw[y]) in df.iloc[0, 0]:
```

or in your case:

```
if str(Keywords_EKN[y]) in df.iloc[x, 12]:
```

or replace `nan` values from the dataframe at the beginning as suggested Timus in comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `if str(Keywords_EKN[y]) in df.iloc[x, 12]:` solved the problem. But I have another error `argument of type 'float' is not iterable`, can you please tell me, what could that be?

Comment: I think, I should search for empty values like this: `if df.iloc[x].isnull().any() & str(Keywords_EKN[z]) in df.iloc[x, 12]:` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @shimaamini no, it's not possible due to nan values in df. I'm also not sure why you need check occurrence of nan values in whole Series. In case a check of column 12 would be sufficient for you, you could use another string condition - `if type(df.iloc[x, 12])==str and str(Keywords_EKN[z]) in df.iloc[x, 12]:`  Float values (incl. nan) are skipped then. But I would consider reworking the code - it looks like comparing two dataframes, so what about `join`? Or `loc`? As far as I know nested loops are mostly not needed in Pandas (and that's why we love it :) )

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I'm new in Python, that's why my code is'nt the best. I'll check `join` and `loc`. Thanks a lot !